# How catch insufficient number of arguments error in python

Tags: python, error-handling

```
def divide(num1, num2):
try:
    result = num1/num2
except (TypeError):
    return "Please provide two integers or floats"
else:
    return result
print(divide(1))
```

Now when I am running these lines I am getting

```
TypeError: divide() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num2'
```

even though I am excepting TypeError.
How to resolve this without using just

```
except:
    #Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs when you call `divide`, not inside it. So you have to write the try/except statement when calling `divide`:

```
try:
   divide(1)
except (TypeError):
    return "Please provide two integers or floats"
```